# Undefined Reference To module_open

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, websocket

I'm going through some C websocket programming code involving a  `module_open` function. I am getting a linker error stating this:

```
/tmp/ccJ3uaHB.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `module_open'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This function is defined in a file `server.h` as:

```
extern struct server_module* module_open (const char* module_path);
```

Now including only relevant code, the function `module_open` is used in `main()` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "server.h"
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct server_module* module = NULL;
    const char* page;

    if(*page == '/' && strchr(page + 1, '/') == NULL)
    {
        char module_file_name[64];
        snprintf(module_file_name, sizeof(module_file_name), "%s.so", page + 1);

         /* Try to open the module.  */
         module = module_open (module_file_name);

    }

}
```

And in case it helps here is the `struct module` from `server.h` as well

```
/* An instance of a loaded server module.  */
struct server_module {
  /* The shared library handle corresponding to the loaded module.  */
  void* handle;
  /* A name describing the module.  */
  const char* name;
  /* The function which generates the HTML results for this module.  */
  void (* generate_function) (int);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try linking with -ldl switch.  I think you're trying to use the Dynamic Loader library right?

Comment: Yes! Just passed `ldl` flag and it works! Thanks for this!